# Ways of improving security of a login page

Tags: security, jsf, authentication, glassfish

Hi guys currently i am using a very basic method of loging a user into the application and that is using the form with a managed bean behind the form with the users username and password, this is fine for a small application with 2 users, however i am looking to increase this and have a registration page etc what would be the best methods to do this are there any good tutorials, i am using netbeans and glassfish

this is my current working login setup

```
    <h:form id="login-form">
       <h:outputText value="username:"/>
       <h:inputText value="#{loginBean.username}" id="username"/>
       <br/>
       <h:outputText value="password:"/>
       <h:inputSecret value="#{loginBean.password}" id="password"/>
       <br/>
       <h:commandButton id="button" value="Login" action="#{loginBean.doLogin}"/>
       <br/>
       <h:commandLink action="#{navigationBean.redirectToInfo}" value="Info page"/>
       <br/>
       <h:messages />
       <br/>
    </h:form>
```

and the bean

```
*/
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7765876811740798583L;

    // Simple user database :)
    private static final String[] users = {"test:test","kate:123456"};

    private String username;
    private String password;

    private boolean loggedIn;

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{navigationBean}")
    private NavigationBean navigationBean;

    /**
     * Login operation.
     * @return
     */
    public String doLogin() {
        // Get every user from our sample database :)
        for (String user: users) {
            String dbUsername = user.split(":")[0];
            String dbPassword = user.split(":")[1];

            // Successful login
            if (dbUsername.equals(username) && dbPassword.equals(password)) {
                loggedIn = true;
                return navigationBean.redirectToWelcome();
            }
        }

        // Set login ERROR
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Login error!", "ERROR MSG");
        msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);

        // To to login page
        return navigationBean.toLogin();

    }

    /**
     * Logout operation.
     * @return
     */
    public String doLogout() {
        // Set the paremeter indicating that user is logged in to false
        loggedIn = false;

        // Set logout message
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Logout success!", "INFO MSG");
        msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);

        return navigationBean.toLogin();
    }

    // ------------------------------
    // Getters & Setters
```

Comment: Start learning SQL databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Improving security" is a pretty broad question.  But three incremental steps you can take are:

1. Store user names/passwords in a database of some sort (unless you have some serious scaling in mind, it really doesn't matter what kind)
2. Don't store passwords, only store hashes of passwords (bcrypt, PBKDF2, or some other cryptographic hashing library which makes hashing computationally expensive)
3. Don't use vanilla HTTP, ever.  If you don't have transport level security you're sending passwords/tokens in the clear and none of the rest matters.  If you're serious about securing a web app, use HTTPS for the entire site.